# Java command line arguments using hh:mm:ss format

Tags: java, time, format, command-line-arguments

I am trying to make a simple program that allows the user to input the startTime and stopTime using command line arguments in the format of hh:mm:ss and prints the duration that the clock runs. I looked in the API in the time section but I couldn't find that format. I read that you could the pass the arguments through the constructor but that didn't work. Here is the code:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Duration;




public class Clock {
    private LocalTime startTime;
    private LocalTime stopTime;
    private Duration duration;
    private int hours, minutes, seconds;


    // no argument constructor that initializes the startTime to the current time
    public Clock() {
        startTime = LocalTime.now();
    }
    public Clock(LocalTime start, LocalTime stop) {
        startTime = start;
        stopTime = stop;
    }


    //public Clock(start, stop) {

    //}

    // resets the startTime to the given time
    public void start(int h, int m, int s) {
        hours = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
        minutes = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
        seconds = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
        startTime = LocalTime.of(hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    //a stop() method that sets the endTime to the given time
    public void stop(int h, int m, int s) {
        hours = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
        minutes = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
        seconds = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
        stopTime = LocalTime.of(hours, minutes, seconds);
    }

    //a getElapsedTime() method that returns the elapsed time in seconds
    public Duration getElapsedTime() {
        System.out.println("Difference is " + Duration.between(stopTime, startTime).
            toNanos()/1_000_000_000.0 + " Seconds.");
        duration = Duration.between(stopTime, startTime);
        return duration;
    }

}
```

Here is the `main` method:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;


public class TestClock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       LocalTime argOne;
       LocalTime argTwo;
       argOne = LocalTime.parse(args[0]);
       argTwo = LocalTime.parse(args[1]);
       Clock clockOne = new Clock(argOne, argTwo);
       System.out.println(clockOne.getElapsedTime());
    }

}
```

Comment: _but that didn't work either_.. What did you expect and what happened? What was the error..

Comment: You mention command line arguments, and then you don't show the `main` method which is the only place where you get the command line arguments. You should show it - and all the code it accesses to get to the methods that you have shown.

Comment: @Codebender - Correct what I said, I meant I tried to pass the arguments directly to the constructor (I read that could be done) but it gave an incompatible type error

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Its added now

Comment: Well, then, you have to parse the arguments into `LocalTime` objects before you pass them. Wherever you read that you didn't have to - either they were wrong or you didn't get it right.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Thank you very much! You just helped me solve it.

Comment: @Bill Yikes! Change the name of your `Clock` class as the java.time framework already has a [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class. I was very confused reading both your Question and Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Well, then, you have to parse the arguments into LocalTime objects before you pass them."      -RealSkeptic

That got me what I needed thanks.

```
public class TestClock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       LocalTime argOne;
       LocalTime argTwo;
       argOne = LocalTime.parse(args[0]);
       argTwo = LocalTime.parse(args[1]);
       Clock clockOne = new Clock(argOne, argTwo);
       clockOne.getElapsedTime();
    }

}
```